# use of the yyleng function in ml-lex

Tags: lex, ml

Could some help me out with the use of the yyleng function of the ml-lex.
How could i use it to display the length of the length of the recently matched text in the analyser

Comment: You might wan't to rephrase your question. It is not completely clear what your exact proble is. As far as I know, then you only have `yypos` and `yytext` in ml-lex. Where you then can take the length of `yytext` to get the length of the matched.

Comment: See the [user guide](http://rogerprice.org/ug/ug.pdf), [here](https://github.com/mortenbp/turtledove/blob/master/code/parsers/sml/SML.lex) or [here](https://github.com/mortenbp/turtledove/blob/master/code/parsers/mlb/MLB.lex) for examples

Answer (score 0):

([This question was answered in the comments. Converted to Community Wiki Answer to suit SO Q&A format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)

@Jesper.Reenberg noted:

> You might wan't to rephrase your question. It is not completely clear what your exact problem is. As far as I know, then you only have `yypos` and `yytext` in ml-lex. Where you then can take the length of `yytext` to get the length of the matched.
>
> See the [user guide](http://rogerprice.org/ug/ug.pdf), [here](https://github.com/mortenbp/turtledove/blob/master/code/parsers/sml/SML.lex) or [here](https://github.com/mortenbp/turtledove/blob/master/code/parsers/mlb/MLB.lex) for examples.